# Multiple tasks, but only the last one seems to actually call the POST API

Tags: c#, post, async-await, task

I am trying to load data from multiple files into database. I have a POST API which I use to parse and try to load every single file. In a second c# app, I need to call this action once for each file, wait for all of them to complete and do other stuff based on the response of each call.
I see that all the tasks are created correctly, but I get the response only for the last POST call.
I am quite new on back end services, so maybe I'm missing something obvious.

This is the code I use for the calls:

```
public static async void ManagedImports(string posturl,
    Dictionary<string, FileInfo> filesInfo)
{
    // Try to import each file
    List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();
    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, FileInfo> file in filesInfo)
    {
        tasks.Add(TryFileImportAsync(url, file));
    }

    // Wait for all the calls to complete before proceeding
    while (tasks.Count > 0)
    {
        Task finishedTask = await Task.WhenAny(tasks);
        tasks.Remove(finishedTask);
    }

    // Do other stuff
}
```

And this is the `TryFileImportAsync` function:

```
public static async Task<string> TryFileImportAsync(string url,
    KeyValuePair<string, FileInfo> fileInfo)
{
    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = token;
        using (var content = new MultipartFormDataContent("FileUpload" +
            DateTime.Now.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)))
        {

            // fileInfo.Key holds the file path 
            content.Add(new ByteArrayContent(File.ReadAllBytes(fileInfo.Key)),
                fileInfo.Value.fileName, fileInfo.Key);

            using (HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(url, content))
            {
                // Inspect and save the response status code to know what to do later
                if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
                {
                    fileInfo.Value.apiOutcome = "ok";
                }
                else if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.BadRequest)
                {
                    ...
                }
                else
                {
                    ...
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return response.ReasonPhrase;
}
```

If I set a breakpoint at the beginning of `TryFileImportAsync` function, I see that all files gets to this point, but only the last one gets to the `PostAsync`, therefore my API will run only for the last file.

Comment: Just use `await Task.WhenAll(tasks)`, also your use of `async void` is suspect,

Comment: How did you test and determine that you "only get response for the last POST call"? It can be challenging to correctly determine what is going on in an application once multiple threads are running the code you're debugging.

Comment: [Avoid async void](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2013/march/async-await-best-practices-in-asynchronous-programming#avoid-async-void). It is intended for asynchronous event handlers only, and most probably your `ManagedImports` method is not an event handler.

Comment: Thanks everybody for the tips about _WhenAll_ and _async void_! I followed your pieces of advice and fixed